# Mat-paginator with multiple dynamic mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In a page of my component I have a dynamically generated mat-table based on the response of an API (so the tabs can be from 1 to n).
Within each tab I have a mat-table with data that always comes to me from an API.
I set the sort and pagination as follows:

component.ts:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Interface>;
@ViewChild('MatPaginatorAS') paginatorAS: MatPaginator | null;
@ViewChild('MatSortAS') sortAS: MatSort | null;
displayedColumnsAs: string [] = ['id']
//Each time I change tabs a function re-executes these commands:
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sortAS;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginatorAS;
```

component.html:

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
   <mat-tab *ngFor="let Phase of Phases; let index = index" [label]="phaseName">
     <table #MatSortAS="matSort" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
       <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el">
          {{el.name}}
         </td>
       </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsAs"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let el; columns: displayedColumnsAs;"></tr>
     </table>
     <mat-paginator #MatPaginatorAS="matPaginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
   </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

But in the first tab it works, while in all others it does not and keeps the setting chosen in the first tab.
I cannot give a different name to the sort and pagination for each tab because I don't know how many there are as they are dynamically generated by the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the code inherent to the tables inside a child component, to which I pass the table data every time I change tabs and in which I do paging and sorting, this way it treats the tables on each page as separate and everything works.

In component.html:

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let Phase of Phases" [label]="phaseName">
         <app-component-child [Phase]="Phase"></app-component-child>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In component-child.html:

```
<table #MatSortAS="matSort" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
       <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el">
          {{el.name}}
         </td>
       </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsAs"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let el; columns: displayedColumnsAs;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator #MatPaginatorAS="matPaginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

In component-child.ts:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Interface>;
@ViewChild('MatPaginatorAS') paginatorAS: MatPaginator | null;
@ViewChild('MatSortAS') sortAS: MatSort | null;
displayedColumnsAs: string [] = ['id']
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(Phase);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sortAS;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginatorAS;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: You have an API that is delivering  1..n Phases (name used in your *ngFor loop) displayed as tabs. When hitting a tab the corresponding data is loaded from an API and should be displayed in a mat-table.

In your HTML, you are generating multiple mat-tables with a matSort and a matPaginator for each table/tab. Therefore you will have multiple matSorts and matPaginators after the view is initialized, so you need to address your paginators(and accordingly the matSorts) in the following way:

`@ViewChildren(MatPaginatorAS) paginators = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();`

This object will contain all paginators in your view.
When initializing your dataSource you need to refer to the paginator that was created in the currently visible/clicked tab.

i.e.: You want to init dataSoruce in tab 2:
`setTimeout(() => {if (!!this.paginators.get(tabIndex)) this.serviceorders[tabIndex].paginator = this.paginators.get(tabIndex)!;}, 200);`

Add-On: I had a quite similar setup lately and I achieved a better performance by initializing a unique matTableDataSource (stored in an array, or dto-object) for each tab and assigning the paginator for each once right after initialization, instead of new every time the tab is clicked.

Haven't tested the code snippets, but I hope it helps!